# How to properly wait while `GET` returns the completion status equal to 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to use API that performs a task in two steps:

1. POST request: to submit a task and get back the results URL
2. GET request: to check for a status of the results URL and get the result when the status is "completed"

Below I provide my implementation. However, I don't know how to perform the `waiting` while `GET` returns the completion status equal to 0.

```
import requests
 
url = "https://xxx"
 
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxx"}
 
body = {...}
 
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
 
status_code = response.status_code
url_result = response.headers['url-result']

# Step 2
s2_result = requests.get(url_result, headers=headers)
s2_result = s2_result.json()
s2_result_status = s2_result['completed']
if s2_result_status == 1:
# ...
else:
# wait 1 second and repeat
```

Comment: Use a while loop and check every second. Add a timeout of sorts and break it if nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the `get` in a loop. I suggest you use `Session()` to prvent connection errors

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    c = 0
    while c < 10: # add a limit
        s2_result = s.get(url_result, headers=headers)
        s2_result = s2_result.json()
        s2_result_status = s2_result['completed']
        if s2_result_status == 1:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            c += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, should `c` be initiated as `c = 0`?

Comment: @Fluxy Yes, of course. And it doesn't have to be 10 tries, you can add whatever limitation you like, but you should limit it not to be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of waiting for 1 second and repeating can definitely solve your problem. You can use `time.sleep(1)`. For example,

```
# Step 2
while True:
    s2_result = requests.get(url_result, headers=headers)
    s2_result = s2_result.json()
    s2_result_status = s2_result['completed']
    if s2_result_status == 1:
    # ...
        break
    else:
    # wait 1 second and repeat
        time.sleep(1)
```

Reminders: Do not forget to check the http status code of response before you call `s2_result.json()`. And, using `s2_result.get('completed')` rather than `s2_result['completed']` makes your program more robust.